# How to install tomcat on ubuntu using salt-master

Tags: salt-stack

I installed salt master and minion on my Ubuntu OS. Now i want to install tomcat server using salt master. 
How can i install Tomcat server using salt-master

I tried like below

```
tomcat:
  archive:
    - extracted
    - name: /opt/
    - source: http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi/apache-tomcat-7.0.47.tar.gz
    - source_hash: md5=efbae77efad579b655ae175754cad3df
    - archive_format: tar
    - tar_options: z
    - if_missing: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.47
```

getting outout like below

```
ubuntu:
----------
          ID: tomcat
    Function: archive.extracted
        Name: /opt/
      Result: False
     Comment: File sum set for file /var/cache/salt/minion/_opt_apache-tomcat-7.0.47.tar of efbae77efad579b655ae175754cad3dd does not match real sum of dbe64e2e9c509f949539b41447a875e5
     Changes:   
              ----------
              diff:
                  New file

Summary
------------
Succeeded: 0
Failed:    1
------------
Total:     1
```

I dont know exactly is this correct way or not

Can any one please help me

Answer (score 0):

The output says it all

```
ubuntu:
----------
          ID: tomcat
    Function: archive.extracted
        Name: /opt/
      Result: False
     Comment: File sum set for file /var/cache/salt/minion/_opt_apache-tomcat-7.0.47.tar of efbae77efad579b655ae175754cad3dd does not match real sum of dbe64e2e9c509f949539b41447a875e5
     Changes:   
              ----------
              diff:
             New file
```

Particularly the message `/var/cache/salt/minion/_opt_apache-tomcat-7.0.47.tar of efbae77efad579b655ae175754cad3dd does not match real sum of dbe64e2e9c509f949539b41447a875e5`. It says you what http request file cached at `/var/cache/salt/minion/_opt_apache-tomcat-7.0.47.tar` does not match the checksum you supplied in state metadata.